# How to eliminate repeated lines in python functions

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

Below is the python function and  every  function will use same repeated lines  in most of the  python functions (more than 200 functions).

So I planned to write it as module and import it as module or any other suggestion would be fine.

Below is the repeated lines that occur in every function.

```
def abc(username, password, host, a, b, c, d, e):

# VARIABLES THAT NEED CHANGED

# Create instance of SSHClient object
   remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Automatically add untrusted hosts (make sure okay for security policy in your environment)
   remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
     paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# initiate SSH connection
   remote_conn_pre.connect(host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
   print "SSH connection established to %s" % host
# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
   remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()

# Send some commands and get the output
```

Second function example:

```
def xyz(username, password, host, a, b):

# VARIABLES THAT NEED CHANGED

# Create instance of SSHClient object
   remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Automatically add untrusted hosts (make sure okay for security policy in your environment)
   remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
     paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# initiate SSH connection
   remote_conn_pre.connect(host, username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
   print "SSH connection established to %s" % host
# Use invoke_shell to establish an 'interactive session'
   remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()

# Send some commands and get the output
```

In above functions  is calling by another scripts.
 Note: Below line is not repeating in every time in function.

```
def abc(username, password, host, a, b, c, d, e)
```

and Every function written with different arguments to the function (Different number of arguments). Example like below

```
def xyz(username, password, host, a, b):
```

1. How to remove repeated lines in all the functions and make it work without any issues.

The above  functions are  used to establish ssh connection Using paramiko.

Comment: What exactly are the "VARIABLES THAT NEED CHANGED"?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just make it a single function, and pass the name of the command along with args to function. Something like this:

```
def run_remote(username, password, host, command, *command_args):
   # Create instance of SSHClient object
   remote_conn = paramiko.SSHClient()

    # Automatically add untrusted hosts (make sure okay for security policy in your environment)
   remote_conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(
     paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

   # initiate SSH connection
   remote_conn.connect(host, 
                       username=username, 
                       password=password, 
                       look_for_keys=False, 
                       allow_agent=False)
   print "SSH connection established to %s" % host
   # execute a remote command and return stdin, stdout, stderr
   args_as_str = ' '.join([pipes.quote(arg) for arg in command_args])
   return remote_conn.exec_command("{} {}".format(command, args_as_str)
```

Comment: `args_as_str = [...]` should be `args_as_str = ' '.join(...)`, also `pipes.quote` the `command`.